# python stops during import

Tags: python, python-3.x

From today I have funny problem. Everything was working just fine for months and today I want to start my program as usual and during import it just exits. There is no error or nothing. I tried over console and in pycharm but result is the same. It seems problem is inside init.py but during import from projects.

import of class looks like this:

```
from engine.database import Database
```

if I try directly to use Database class from the database.py it works. What has changed, I'm using python 3.6?

## EDIT:

in engine directory I have init.py like this:

```
# Database imports
from engine.database import Database
# Tor imports
from projects.Common.tor_network import TorBuild
from projects.Common.tor_network import Check
from projects.Common.tor_network import kill_all
```

if I comment imports from project it works.

**Because imports from projects doesn't work. Here is other init.py files** 
init.py in projects looks like this:

```
from projects.Common import *
```

and inside projects/Common init.py looks like this:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import abspath, dirname, isfile, join
# get location of __init__.py
init_path = abspath(__file__)
# get folder name of __init__.py
init_dir = dirname(init_path)
# get all python files
py_files = [file_name.replace(".py", "") for file_name in listdir(init_dir) \
           if isfile(join(init_dir, file_name)) and ".py" in file_name and not ".pyc" in file_name]
# remove this __init__ file from the list
py_files.remove("__init__")
__all__ = py_files
```

## EDIT2:

So source of the problem is located in projects/Common init.py.
If I replace the that code only with `__all__ = ['tor_network']` it will work. But that would mean I have to install manualy everytime I add program. That is really funny thing. I worked for moths now it doesnt.

## EDIT3:

Ok I found the problem... One of program inside Common was runing function (I forgot to comment later) that exits after run. I forgot on that one.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Check the `__init__.py` in the folder `engine`.

Comment: I have there __init__,py  and inside imports like from engine.database import Database.. I tried from engine import Database also doesn't work. Oh ok I have other imports inside also when I comment them it works. hmm I guess I know where the problem is.

Comment: Inside `__init__.py` write: `from engine.database import Database`. And in your script call this like: `from engine import Database`. Try this.

Comment: That part works it seems it is not problem inside init.py  for from engine.database import Database. But for imports from projects. Look my edit above please.